# Print characters the same amount as a value stored in a variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, project

So uh, take a look at this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int charOne=12
 cout << endl;
 return 0;
```

So my goal is to write the character "E" (charOne) times with while/for loop statements.
So, the output must be this: EEEEEEEEEEEE.
Can somebody teach me how to code this thing? Thanks!

I've tried this one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int charOne=12
while(charOne >= 12)
    cout << E;
```

But it showed infinite E's

Answer (score 0):

You have no breaking condition in the loop so the loop never terminates. The correct code would be

```
 while(charOne!=0){
    cout << "E";
    charOne--;
}
```

In your code you have the condition `charOne >= 12` which resolves to true each time because `charOne is 12 and you never alter it's value in the loop` and hence the loop never terminates. Whenever you write a loop always have a breaking condition so that the loop ends after a finite number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a loop to check if charOne is greater than or equal to 12, and if so print E and repeat loop. But nothing ever changes value so depending on the value of charOne you loop will either do nothing, or go into an endless loop printing E's.

you could fix by doing the following

```
while (charOne-- > 0)
    cout << "E";
```

but you probably want to do the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < charOne; i++)
    cout << "E";
```